# IOS Obj-C extracting latitude from CLLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm updating an Obj-C project, and a model for a "upload model" is made with a `CLLocation` of similar to this:
NSLog output:

> <+38.03744507,+122.80317688> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 8/23/16, 9:44:41 PM Central European Summer Time

So I would assume I could just extract that data as this:

```
CLLocation *lat = self.currentUploadPackage.placeLocation.coordinate.latitude;
```

I get to `placeLocation`, but Xcode claims that it doesn't contain `coordinate` nor `latitude`

> (/Users/user/Development/app/ShareDescriptionViewController.m:92:37: Property 'latitude' cannot be found in forward class object 'CLLocation')

How do I go about getting the long/lat data from the `CLLocation` mentioned above? Or any hints.

(PS: I am not good with ObjC, as I focused on Swift)

Comment: what is self.currentUploadPackage?

Comment: and btw drop the * as CLLocation object is an object, not a pointer

Comment: @SahebRoy No, the pointer is required with `CLLocation`.

Comment: What is the datatype of currentUploadPackage variable? latitude is a CLLocationDegrees/double type data.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the error mentions "forward class object 'CLLocation'".

This means you use `@class CLLocation` somewhere (probably in some .h file). But this doesn't provide any details about `CLLocation` other than it is some class.

To fix your code you need to import the proper .h file in the .m file that actually tries to access properties of `CLLocation`.

```
#import <CoreLocation/CLLocation.h>
```